# DB::select failing in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a Laravel 5.2.45 application, also, I have a complex  query to do, so I tried to consult it using:

```
DB::select("the query");
```

I read that this should work, but it's not the case, so just testing I simplified the query to: `"Select * from aTable"` but it also doesn't give any result, it takes a long long timeloading the webpage and then just doesnt show anything. I'm using this exactly: `dd(DB::select("SELECT * FROM myTable AS mt"))`

So, I'm wondering what is exaclty happening, it's still a valid function in Laravel 5.2? it's a really simple query and am not sure in what is failing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects to see proper usage of DB::select()

Comment: @stereoscience that doesn't help. I already read that and it is not the case.

Comment: Here are the correct docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries It's difficult to know which way to point you in without seeing the real query. Also what is the dd method for?

Comment: try executing that query in your dbms

Comment: `DB::table('testable')->where("Condition Here")->get();`

Comment: When everything fails CORE PHP comes into action. ;)

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova Run same select into phpmyadmin and confirm that no problem comes from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to execute raw query. If you execute raw query in laravel please try this way:

`$tableData = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 100 ") );
dd($tableData);`

You can set custom function also for printing data in your helper function like

`function pr($var){
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($var);
     echo "</pre>";
  }`

than you can call `pr($tableData);`

I think this should work for you. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but you can check your Query Log to find problem

```
     $users = DB::select('SELECT * FROM myTable AS mt');
     print_r(DB::enableQueryLog());
```

How to enable query log

> https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e0abfe5c49d225567cb4dfd56df9ef05cc297448

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$users = DB::table('myTable')->get();